# selenium открыть локальный html документ

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Использую c#. В интернете видел примеры

```
IWebDriver driver;
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("-no-sandbox");
driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverDirectory, options, TimeSpan.FromHours(2));
driver.get("C:\\Users\\sharmayo\\Desktop\\testlogin.html");
```

но почему-то выдаёт
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего вы видели пример кода на java, а он похож на C#. На С# можно использовать **driver.Navigate().GoToUrl()**. Локальный файл можно открыть через браузер и скопировать путь из поисковой строки. Вероятно нужно добавить этот аргумент **options.AddArgument("--allow-file-access-from-files");**